# ошибка: if (played_date[0], points_on_account[0]) == (0): TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable "

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

не совсем понял, в чем заключается проблема, хотя похожие вопросы я изучил

````
   cur = con.cursor()
   current_date = str(datetime.now()).split()[0]
   cur.execute("SELECT date_played FROM users WHERE userId=?", (message.from_user.id,))
   played_date = cur.fetchone()
   cur.execute("SELECT points FROM users WHERE userId=?", (message.from_user.id,))
   points_on_account = cur.fetchone()
   if (played_date[0], points_on_account[0]) == (None, 0):```
````

Comment: cur.fetchone() что именно выдает в обоих случаях? Уверены, что points_on_account[0] - не None, например?